# Kendo ui datagrid

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am just trying to use keno ui into my project. But Kendo is new to me. So I am not sure how to proper use it. Some of the widgets like dialog window, datepicker, timepicker etc. are easy to use but I am having problem with datagird. Could anybody let me know how can we use datagrid widget server databound and xml as datatype. Please give me little bit give me an example. If possible. Let me know how xml file will look. How can we get page number, number of rows on the server side. I am using asp.net with c# as server side language.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you want to bind to an xml file? Generally speaking you should be using JSON for the dataSource. For an example of using an xml datasource have you looked at this:

[Binding to xml DataSource](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/xml-data)

If you haven't used these before and have access to the MVC Wrappers then I would suggest looking at this demo as a good starting place for the Grid:

[Kendo Grid bound to local data](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding)

[Kendo Grid bound to remote data](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/remote-data-binding)

If you use the demo from the first example and apply it to the "local data" example this should get you going. If you get stuck please provide some code showing what you have tried and any issues you are faced with.